# Can I specify a folder when creating container images?

Tags: debian, docker, container

When I create a new container, this error always occurs after a period of time. Even if I delete some images with command `docker rmi dobotv4vc_2:v450stable_v2 && docker rmi dobotv4vc:450stable_v2`, this error still occurs. Therefore, I have to use commands `docker system prune -a` to clean up. Although this can solve the problem, it will clean up all the images, which is not what I want because I want to keep some images that are only built once. Can I specify a folder instead of using the default `/var` when I want to create container images, as my computer's partition `/home` has a lot of storage space?

error:

```
Error response from daemon: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-4186096899/ce3cb6d0076be36c2265b2a0a977320d8bd8a628907e3bc44be967f9bcab492e/layer.tar: no space left on device
```

the information of my pc:

```
debian12@gyz:~/share/v4vc$ docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
dobotv4vc_2   v450stable_v2   06d439cb51c5   11 hours ago   797MB
dobotv4vc     450stable_v2    f27356a72ac9   37 hours ago   803MB
v4os          v2.0            f1dcedaf0739   37 hours ago   505MB
dobotv4vc     v450stable_v1   b5fc1faf7f4e   47 hours ago   1.09GB
v4os          v1.4            28692487a06f   12 days ago    559MB
debian12@gyz:~/share/v4vc$ df -h
文件系统        大小  已用  可用 已用% 挂载点
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G    0% /dev
tmpfs           789M   24M  765M    4% /run
/dev/sda2        23G  9.2G   13G   43% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M    0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M  5.9M  506M    2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda5       1.8G   64K  1.7G    1% /tmp
/dev/sda3       9.1G  8.5G  112M   99% /var
/dev/sda6       423G   36G  366G    9% /home
tmpfs           789M   32K  789M    1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `/var` filesystem is 99% full, and Docker by default uses `/var/lib/docker` for storage. You can change the location of Docker's backing store by setting the [`data-root` option in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#daemon-data-directory).

Your issue is a good illustration of why it often does **not** make sense to have a separate `/var` partition. For a standard home desktop/laptop, it is often much more convenient to have a single `/` filesystem (that includes both `/var` and `/home`) so that you have maximum flexibility with space.

You may want to investigate `/var` to identify the major consumer of space. If it's Docker, you may be able to free up some space by pruning dangling images (`docker image prune`) and stopped containers (`docker container prune`).

Comment: Sorry, there was an issue with my previous description. The cleaning command I used should be `docker system prune - a`, not `docker image prune&&docker container prune`. I have investigated and found that Docker is the main consumer of `/var`. I use `docker Image prune&&docker container prune`, but still haven't cleared up space.